# Springmvc form tags on appengine error Failed to compile jsp files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am getting the following error on deployment to app engine on my application that makes use of springmvc. I have seen similar postings on custom jstl tags but none relating to springmvc form tags. I have also followed this thread at http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/d93fd7385bf85bf7 to register PropertyEditors. After running the appcfg script from the command line, I am getting the following error specifically pointing to springframework form tags:

```
Reading application configuration data...
Mar 30, 2011 7:11:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader
 readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed AllData/netBeans_Projects/Listings/web\WEB-INF/appe
ngine-web.xml
Mar 30, 2011 7:11:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlRead
er readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed AllData/netBeans_Projects/Listings/web\WEB-INF/web.
xml
Beginning server interaction for opevel-listings...
0% Creating staging directory
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.

Error Details:
Mar 30, 2011 7:11:59 PM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \redirect.jsp
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri:
http://www.springframework.org/tags/form cannot be resolved in either web.xml or
 the jar files deployed with this application
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorH
andler.java:51)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.j
ava:409)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.j
ava:116)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(Tag
LibraryInfoImpl.java:315)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoIm
pl.java:148)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:38
6)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:449)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1396)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.
java:255)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.ja
va:103)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:
18)
Error while executing: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\jre\bin\java.exe -classpath /D:/appen
gine-java-sdk-1.4.2/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar;/D:/appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2
/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar;/D:/appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2/lib/impl/appengin
e-api.jar;/D:/appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar;D:\a
ppengine-java-sdk-1.4.2\lib\shared\appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar;D:\appengi
ne-java-sdk-1.4.2\lib\shared\el-api.jar;D:\appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2\lib\shared\j
sp\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;D:\appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2\lib\shared\jsp
\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;D:\appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2\lib\sha
red\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;D:\appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2\lib\s
hared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;D:\appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2\
lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;D:\appengine-java-sdk
-1.4.2\lib\shared\jsp-api.jar;D:\appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2\lib\shared\servlet-api
.jar;D:\appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2\lib\shared\tools.jar;C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCAL
S~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tmp\WEB-INF\classes;C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appc
fg56538.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\
LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.
1.jar;C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-
appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar;C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.
tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar;C:\DOCUME~1\ADMI
NI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.2
9.jar;C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-
appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tm
p\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar;C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LO
CALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.
jar; com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC -uriroot C:\DOCUME~1\ADMIN
I~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tmp -p org.apache.jsp -l -v -webinc C:\DOCUME~1\AD
MINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tmp\WEB-INF\generated_web.xml -d C:\DOCUME~1\AD
MINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56538.tmp\WEB-INF\classes -compile -javaEncoding UTF-
8


com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp
files.
Unable to update app: Failed to compile jsp files.
Please see the logs [C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg56537.log] for fur
ther information.
```

Will appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: To compile jsp files. you need to install jdk. JRE won't help. Are you using jdk

Comment: Make sure you have Spring jars in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? Do you know that you should accept answers on your questions by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer?

Comment: @axtavt I used ant (bundled with Netbeans IDE) to build the project. So in the directory build/web/WEB-INF/lib, all required jars including spring-webmvc has been included. My project uses spring-webmvc-3.0.2. This jar is included as well.

@Abdul, according to instructions from similar posts on the web, it says I should copy tools.jar to appengine shared directory. This way appcfg will make use of JDK java.exe instead of JRE. This I have done by changing the appcfg script to @%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java. But after running the command, it's still making use of java in JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the command for the appdir from

"appcfg --enable_jar_splitting update path/to/project/web path/to/project/dist/" to

"appcfg --enable_jar_splitting update path/to/project/build/web path/to/project/dist/"

Regards